# "unknown transitions listed in local; upgrade git-annex!"

Tags: git-annex

I'm not sure what is happening anymore. I disabled the assistant so I can set up what I wanted to exclude from certain repositories, after which I decided to just not use the assistant. Started working per usual with my repositories and now this error appears:

```
unknown transitions listed in local; upgrade git-annex!
```

This appears whenever I use `enableremote`, `fsck`, `get`, `move`, `drop`, and others. I've checked the [source of this line](https://github.com/joeyh/git-annex/blob/master/Logs/Transitions.hs#L61), but I don't know what it means.

Comment: Check your `transitions.log` in your git-annex branch (e.g., `git cat-file blob refs/heads/git-annex:transitions.log`)

Comment: @derobert it just mentions `/annex/objects/SHA256E-s36--a2f592dff3f3fb89b0e896bdbc59a0c963be7069a9f360e1d50685973c5f0b22.log
ForgetGitHistory 1473717741.220983s` I can't find that "file" anywhere.

Comment: Pretty sure that "/annex/object…" bit shouldn't be there; I checked several of my repositories and they all have lines starting with e.g., "ForgetGitHistory" or "ForgetDeadRemotes". Have you seen if plain `git fsck` passes?

Comment: @derobert it reports a bunch of dangling blobs and 3 commits, but apparently that is common in my repos.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd suggest checking the git history, see when it got corrupted. Probably easiest to use git worktree or just make a clone, then check out the git-annex branch. Then you can use normal stuff like git blame. (Not sure you want to switch branches in your real repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that somehow the git tree for 3 of my 4 repositories was... incomplete? If I removed all remotes but my bup repository the message disappeared but `git annex sync` still failed with a "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories", which [should have been fixed in April](https://git-annex.branchable.com/todo/support_--allow-unrelated-histories_in_git_2.8.1pre/). I decided using `git fetch --all` for all repositories, manually merged with the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option, uninit'ed all the repositories and rebuilt them from scratch. The "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories" appeared again since I have [several disconnected repositories](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/migrating_two_seperate_disconnected_directories_to_git_annex/) with more or less the same set of files but [I knew how to resolve that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938036/792066)

Comment: I lost a single bib file, probably when I was playing with unused and drop.